# How to unit test with redux selectors

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am currently unit testing this file but I have no idea on how to unit test the two constants I have in redux (grid and list).

**file**

```
const Projects = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const view = useSelector(selectView);

  useMount(() => {
    dispatch(projectsActions.viewRestore());
    dispatch(projectsActions.filterRestore());
  });

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <div className="projects-toolbar" data-testid="projects-toolbar-container">
        <Toolbar />
      </div>

      {view === VIEW_TYPES.grid && <ProjectsGridView />}
      {view === VIEW_TYPES.list && <ProjectsListView />}
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

**test file**

```
    test('renders properly', () => {
    const { getByTestId,  } = setup();

    expect(getByTestId('projects-toolbar-container')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

As you guys see the only test I could do is adding a ID to the Toolbar components outer div to see if it is there but besides that I have no idea on how to check if the constants match to render the other 2 components

Answer (score 0):

When testing a component which uses `redux` . You can use this library [redux mock store](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-mock-store) which helps you to mock the store value.

Now in your test file you can do

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

const store = mockStore({
    view: 'your value here' // now your component will use this value
});
```

Now inside the render of your test file wrap your component with

```
 <Provider store={store}>
        <Projects /> 
 </Provider>
```

**Note**

Please note that this library is designed to test the action-related logic, not the reducer-related one. In other words, it does not update the Redux store.